# Elixir loop over a matrix

Tags: recursion, matrix, erlang, elixir

I have a list of elements and I am converting it into a list of lists using the `Enum.chunk_every` method.

The code is something like this:

```
matrix = Enum.chunk_every(list_1d, num_cols)
Now I want to loop over the matrix and access the neighbors
```

Simply if I have the list [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3] it is converted to a 3X3 matrix like:

[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]]

Now how do I loop over this matrix? And what if I want to access the neighbors of the elements? For example the neighbors of 5 are 2,4,6 and 2.

I can see that recursion is a way to go but how will that work here?

Comment: Do you have more than one two level deep lists? Recursion works well for lists of arbitrary depth. Also, please clarify why neighbours of 5 are 2,4,5 and 2?

Comment: If you want random access in a 2D matrix efficiently you either need to (a) make it immutable (using tuples) or else (b) build the neighbor structure yourself using say a process for each matrix element -which is worth it for sparse matrices.

Comment: @denis.peplin I can have a 100x100 matrix. By neighbors I mean if the element is `(i,j)` then its neighbors are `(i+1,j)`, `(i-1,j)`, `(i,j-1)` and `(i,j+1)`

The example that I gave was slightly wrong. I meant the neighbors for 5 are 2 (i-1, j), 4 (i, j-1), 6 (i, j+1) and 2 (i+1,j).

Does this help you?

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff I don't want random access. I want to access neighbors. I was also looking at tuples, sine the access time will be really less. How do I go about that?

Comment: Have a look at this article http://blog.danielberkompas.com/2016/04/23/multidimensional-arrays-in-elixir.html  which ends up using maps for a games of tic-tac-toe

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this, and I think that you should consider first what is your use case (size of the matrix, number of matrices, number of accesses...) and adapt your data structure accordingly.

Nevertheless, here is a simple implementation (in Erlang shell, I let you adapt to elixir):

```
1> L = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [1,2,3]].
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]
2> Get = fun(I,J,L) -> 
            try
               V = lists:nth(I,lists:nth(J,L)),
               {ok,V}
            catch
               _:_ -> {error,out_of_bound}
            end
          end.
#Fun<erl_eval.18.99386804>
3> Get(1,2,L).
{ok,4}
4> Get(2,3,L).
{ok,2}
5> Get(2,4,L).     
{error,out_of_bound}
6> Neighbor = fun(I,J,L) ->
                [ V || {I1,J1} <- [{I,J-1},{I-1,J},{I+1,J},{I,J+1}],
                       {ok,V} <- [Get(I1,J1,L)]
                ]
              end.                 
#Fun<erl_eval.18.99386804>
7> Neighbor(2,2,L).                                                                                            
[2,4,6,2]
8> Neighbor(1,2,L).
[1,5,1]
9>
```

Remark: I like list comprehension, you may prefer to use lists:map in this case. This code is not efficient since it parses 4 time the list to get the neighbors. The only advantage is that it is "straight". so it should be easy to read.